# How to allow non-authorized user to reach a get method

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt

I'm working on an application where I allow users access by their role. This is configured by a data annotation on the controller level.

```
 [Authorize(Roles = ("Super user,Admin"))]
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class UsersController: ControllerBase
 {

 }
```

This works perfectly with my Angular frontend.

The issue here is that I want to enable just one get method to a user not allowed in authorize annotation.

Method is:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(int id)
```

and I want to allow access to a user named "basic user"?

Any ideas?

Kind regards and many thanks for your support

Edit:

I found that if i make Controller:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = ("Basic user,Super user,Admin"))]
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
 public class UsersController: ControllerBase
 {

 }
```

i can specify other endpoints to:

```
[Authorize(Roles = ("Super user,Admin"))]
```

And they are protected, not exactly what i wanted.

Comment: I'm confused. You want the GetUser method to not be accessed by anyone except for an User whos name is "Basic user"?

Comment: i want to allow access just for this endpoint to another user not named in 
 [Authorize(Roles = ("Super user,Admin"))]

something like  [Authorize(Roles = ("Basic user,Super user,Admin"))]
without putting annotations to every endpoint

Comment: So in the end, your GetUser is accessed by Roles: Super User, Admin, and Username: basic user?

Comment: Did you try adding  [Authorize(Roles = ("Basic user,Super user,Admin"))] to GetUser?

Comment: yup, this is the only method that can be accessed by "basic user" in this controller. There can't be anonymous access

Comment: @Oram yes i did, it doesn't work

Comment: So I guess you'll need to put the Authorize attribute on every method instead of putting it on the class level.

Comment: Try adding [Authorize(Users="Basic user"] on your get method. I'm not sure if the end rules will be that you need to be class rules AND method rules, or class rules OR method rules.

Comment: Another option is to write a different controller and make the router go to it.

Comment: @Erndob i did, and it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 interesting methods of achieving your goal:

***Method A.*** extend the `Authorize` class

```
internal class MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "MinimumAge";

    public MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute(int age) => Age = age;

    // Get or set the Age property by manipulating the underlying Policy property
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            if (int.TryParse(Policy.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX.Length), out var age))
            {
                return age;
            }
            return default(int);
        }
        set
        {
            Policy = $"{POLICY_PREFIX}{value.ToString()}";
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[MinimumAgeAuthorize(10)]
public IActionResult RequiresMinimumAge10()
```

***Method B.*** Create policy and use the [Authorize] attribute to set a "policy" `[Authorize(Policy = "CustomPolicy")]`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[Authorize(Policy = "AtLeast21")]
public class AlcoholPurchaseController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Login() => View();

    public IActionResult Logout() => View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Authorize attributes on every method of the controller instead of the class. Then you control the Authorization for every method separately.

Put just `[Authorize]` on the `GetUser` method so any user can call it. And the `[Authorize(Roles = ("Super user,Admin"))]` to all other methods in the controller.

Comment: true, but I wanted to avoid that because of all the noise in the code

Comment: I think this does not introduce so much noise and is much simpler than doing custom implementations like suggested in the other answer. You should anyway not have a lot of methods in one controller. Else maybe think about splitting into multiple controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to split a class or put all of the attributes on everything, another option is allowing that method to everyone, but then implementing the check yourself.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(int id)
{
  if(!User.IsInRole("Super user") && !User.IsInRole("Admin") && User.Identity.Name != "Basic User")
  {
     return Unauthorized
  }

  Logic from before
}
```